# GMAT: How to do a Hohmann transfer from a larger orbit to a smaller orbit

Tags: hohmann-transfer, gmat

I've figured out how to do a Hohmann transfer to a larger orbit but can't seem to figure out how to do one back to a smaller orbit (e.g. GEO to random smaller orbit). Any advice would be amazing, thanks!

edit: New to GMAT and trying to do it in GMAT

```
BeginMissionSequence;
Propagate 'Prop to peri' DefaultProp(Sat1) {Sat1.Earth.Periapsis, OrbitColor = [255 0 0]};
Target 'Reverse Hohmann' DefaultDC {SolveMode = Solve, ExitMode = DiscardAndContinue, ShowProgressWindow = true};
  Vary 'Vary TOI' DefaultDC(TOI.Element1 = 1, {Perturbation = 0.0001, Lower = -10, Upper = 10, MaxStep = 0.002, AdditiveScaleFactor = 0.0, MultiplicativeScaleFactor = 1.0});  
  Maneuver 'Perform TOI' TOI(Sat1);   
  Propagate 'Prop to apo' DefaultProp(Sat1) {Sat1.Earth.Apoapsis, OrbitColor = [77 77 242]};   
  Achieve 'Achieve RMAG = 7228' DefaultDC(Sat1.Earth.RMAG = 7178, {Tolerance = 0.1});   
  Vary 'Vary GOI' DefaultDC(GOI.Element1 = 1, {Perturbation = 0.0001, Lower = -10, Upper = 10, MaxStep = 0.002, AdditiveScaleFactor = 0.0, MultiplicativeScaleFactor = 1.0});  
  Maneuver 'Perform GOI' GOI(Sat1);  
  Achieve 'Achieve ECC = 0.003471' DefaultDC(Sat1.Earth.ECC = 0.003471, {Tolerance = 0.000001});
EndTarget;  % For targeter DefaultDC
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is a bit vague, I'm assuming you aren't in space at the moment and that you are trying to do the math, use a tool/python module, or play a game like Kerbal. Which is it and what have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do it in GMAT

Comment: That's good to know @SexySloth, could you expand on what you've tried and what doesn't work? Insert some code and results.

Comment: Basically tried the normal manoeuvre but in reverse and played around with it a bunch. Main error I kept getting was that it wouldn't converge. What's the best way to send scripts here?

Comment: If you edit there's tools for adding code, look for the squiggly brackets.

Comment: Added in the post, thank you :)

Comment: Just a guess by glancing at your code, but is it possible that the `Prop to apo` step results in zero actual propagation, since an (instantaneous) orbit-lowering maneuver results in the satellite being at its apogee? Maybe try propagating to perigee instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to set `TOI.Element1` to -1 (*Initial Value*) in the `Vary 'Vary TOI'` command.
2. It looks like you use too small `MaxStep` (0.002) for the `TOI.Element1` in both `Vary` commands. Try to change it to 0.2 or 0.1. GMAT needs more iterations with your settings for the convergence.

Honestly, I did not see (and use) before more than one burn (impulsive or finite) in the same `Target` command. But your code works with mentioned modifications. Thanks!